# Logic app do not triggers alert after the first alert even meeting the condition

Tags: azure, triggers, alert, azure-logic-apps

My logic app is continuously polling to SFTP location every min.
I have an alert(email) on it if skipped continuously for 5 minutes(i.e. 5 times).

Even after meeting the alert condition it only triggers an alert for once.If I update any conditions in alert rule then it again triggers for once and then stops triggering even it met its condition.

I have added the alert on **Trigger Skipped** . The logic app trigger is skipping from last 1 hour.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no configuration errors, you may refer to this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-overview

The tutorial shows:

[image]

The example is for VM, but it's same to our case.
I test another alert(**Runs Started**). I received the alert email just once, but after a few minutes, I received another email to notify me the azure monitor alert was resolved. And after that, I can receive the alert email again if the count > 4.(below is the screenshot of my "resolved" email)

[image]

Comment: My alert was working as expected but i was unable to reproduce the scenario, your provided link made me clear to reproduce. Thanks!